# How to position a view vertically between two other views in android?

Tags: android, textview

I am using relative layout for my application. I want to position a view inbetween two other views. I don't have any nesting and I was wondering if this could be accomplished without that.

My XML code is pretty long and messy so I'm just posting the relevant parts. If you need more please tell me:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/maze_algorithm_spinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/random_textview"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/play"
    android:entries="@array/maze_generation_array"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/maze_algorithm_textview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/maze_algorithm_spinner"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/help"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:text="@string/maze_algorithm_spinner_text"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"/>
```

I basically what `Choose algorithm` textview and its spinner to be centered vertically in between `Random Generation` textview and `Driver` textview.

Here is what my app screen currently looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using RelativeLayout as parent try this:

```
<RelativeLayout ...>
    <LinearLayout 
       android:id="@+id/random_generation_layout"... (responsible for randomGeneration)
       android:alignParentTop="true" >
       <TextView ... />
       <etc>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
       android:id="@+id/choose_algo_layout"... (responsible for ChooseAlgorithm)
       android:layout_above="@+id/driver_layout"
       android:layout_below="@+id/random_generation_layout" >
       <TextView ... />
       <etc>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
       android:id="@+id/driver_layout"... (responsible for driver) 
       android:alignParentBottom="true">
       <TextView ... />
       <etc>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope it wil help you!

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* don't want nesting then you probably want to try adding two transparent `View` in between, where these two `View` elements are of the same height. So it will be like

```
<RandomGeneration />
<View />
<ChooseAlgorithm />
<View />
<Drive />
```

On the other hand, without using extra `View`s, with your dimension currently set to `wrap_content`, you can also assign paddings to `<ChooseAlgorithm />`,  such that your top padding is the same as the bottom padding. The same goes for margin too. You can use either padding or margin, or both.